# Slider control: border is invisible until I press and drag it

Tags: slider, codenameone

Why can't I see the slider bar in iOS and Android, only the thumb? In the simulator it's visible all the time. I have defined Slider and SliderFull in theme.res under "Unselected", and nowhere else.

Comment: How did you define Slider & SliderFull? I suggest placing screenshots of the theme settings. Make sure to also define them in selected state too.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround: defining the styles in code instead of in the gui builder.